# "Spotting" probability density functions of distributions programmatically (Symbolic Toolbox)

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have a joint probability density `f(x,y,z)` and I wish to find the conditional distribution `X|Y=y,Z=z`, which is equivalent to treating `x` as data and `y` and `z` as parameters (constants).

For example, if I have `X|Y=y,Z=z` being the pdf of a `N(1-2y,3z^2+2)`,  the function would be:

```matlab
syms x y z
f(y,z) = 1/sqrt(2*pi*(3*z^2+2)) * exp(-1/(2*(3*z^2+2)) * (x-(1-2*y))^2);
```

I would like to compare it to the following:

```matlab
syms mu s L a b
Normal(mu,s) = (1/sqrt(2*pi*s^2)) * exp(-1/(2*s^2) * (x-mu)^2);
Exponential(L) = L * exp(-L*x);
Gamma(a,b) = (b^a / gamma(a)) * x^(a-1)*exp(-b*x);
Beta(a,b) = (1/beta(a,b)) * x^(a-1)*(1-x)^(b-1);
```

---

### Question

How do I make a program `whichDistribution` that would be able to print which of these four, `f` is equivalent to (up to proportionality) with respect to the variable `x`, and what are the parameters? E.g. `f` and `x` as above, the distribution is `Normal, mu=1-2*y, s=3*z^2+2`.

NB: there would not always be a unique solution, since some distributions are are equivalent (e.g. `Gamma(1,L)==Exponential(L)`)

---

### Desired outputs

```matlab
syms x y z
f = 1/sqrt(2*pi*(3*z^2+2)) * exp(-1/(2*(3*z^2+2)) * (x-(1-2*y))^2)
whichDistribution(f,x) %Conditional X|Y,Z
% Normal(1-2*y,3*z^2+2)
```

```matlab
syms x y
f = y^(1/2)*exp(-(x^2)/2 - y/2 * (1+(4-x)^2+(6-x)^2)) % this is not a pdf because it is missing a constant of proportionality, but it should still work

whichDistribution(f,x)  %Conditional X|Y
% Normal(10*y/(2*y+1), 1/(2*y+1))

whichDistribution(f,y)  %Conditional Y|X
% Gamma(3/2, x^2 - 10*x + 53/2)
```

```matlab
f = exp(-x) %also missing a constant of proportionality
whichDistribution(f,x)
% Exponential(1)
```

```matlab
f = 1/(2*pi)*exp(-(x^2)/2 - (y^2)/2)
whichDistribution(f,x)
% Normal(0,1)
whichDistribution(f,y)
% Normal(0,1)
```

---

What I have tried so far:

1. Using `solve()`:

```matlab
q = solve(f(y,z) == Normal(mu,s), mu, s)
```

Which gives wrong results, since parameters can't depend on `x`:

```matlab
>> q.mu
ans =
(z1^2*(log((2^(1/2)*exp(x^2/(2*z1^2) - (x + 2*y - 1)^2/(6*z^2 + 4)))/(2*pi^(1/2)*(3*z^2 + 2)^(1/2))) + pi*k*2i))/x
>> q.s
ans =
z1
```

2. Attempting to simplify `f(y,z)` up to proportionality (in `x` variable) using a `propto()` function that I wrote:

```matlab
>> propto(f(y,z),x)
ans =
exp(-(x*(x + 4*y - 2))/(2*(3*z^2 + 2)))

>> propto(Normal(mu,s),x)
ans =
exp((x*(2*mu - x))/(2*s^2))
```

This is almost on the money, since it is easy to spot that `s^2=3*z^2 + 2` and `2*mu=-(4*y - 2)`, but I don't know how to deduce this programmatically.

---

---

In case it is useful: `propto(f,x)` attempts to simplify `f` by dividing `f` by children of `f` which don't involve `x`, and then output whichever form has the least number of children. Here is the routine:

```matlab
function out = propto(f,x)
oldf = f;
newf = propto2(f,x);
while (~strcmp(char(oldf),char(newf))) % if the form of f changed, do propto2 again. When propto2(f) == f, stop
    oldf = newf;
    newf = propto2(oldf,x);
end
out = newf;
end
```

```matlab
function out = propto2(f,x)
t1 = children(expand(f)); % expanded f
i1 = ~has([t1{:}],x);
out1 = simplify(f/prod([t1{i1}])); % divides expanded f by terms that do not involve x

t2 = children(f); % unexpanded f
i2 = ~has([t2{:}],x);
out2 = simplify(f/prod([t2{i2}])); % divides f by terms that do not involve x

A = [f, symlength(f); out1, symlength(out1); out2, symlength(out2)];
A = sortrows(A,2); % outputs whichever form has the fewest number of children
out = A(1,1);
end
```

```matlab
function L = symlength(f)
% counts the number of children of f by repeatingly applying children() to itself
t = children(f);
t = [t{:}];
L = length(t);
if (L == 1)
    return
end
oldt = f;
while(~strcmp(char(oldt),char(t)))
    oldt = t;
    t = children(t);
    t = [t{:}];
    t = [t{:}];
end
L = length(t);
end
```

---

edit: added desired outputs

edit2: clarified the desired function

Comment: Dunno if Matlab is an appropriate environment for this problem, although maybe you have external constraints which are motivating that. Anyway, one workable way to look at this is that it's a pattern matching or expression unification problem. Note that pattern matching means matching expressions in this context, not strings. Basically you have some templates, e.g something times exp(-1/2 times other stuff), and given an expression, you want to match "something" to one part and "other stuff" to another part. Take a look at Maxima (https://maxima.sourceforge.io) and Sympy (https://sympy.org).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. SymPy looks very strong and highly developed, although I am not very familiar with Python, in particular not familiar enough to be able to pose an equivalent question in the Python stackoverflow. However I would be happy to accept a working solution written in Python as long as I am able to implement it. I don't have any external constraints, so I am happy with anything that would output the correct results.

Comment: I'm not aware of any projects or libraries for the problem you described, and although there might still be something, I think you might have to do it yourself. I think it's fair to say this is a widely recognized problem, so if you come up with something, others will be interested. You can try the Google group for sympy, or if you want to try Maxima, see the maxima-discuss mailing list. I can help with Maxima. A web search will find the sympy group or maxima-discuss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve my own problem using `solve()` from Symbolic Toolbox. There were two issues with my original approach: I needed to set up `n` simultaneous equations for `n` parameters, and the `solve()` doesn't cope well with exponentials:

```matlab
solve(f(3) == g(3), f(4) == g(4), mu,s)
```

yields no solutions, but

```matlab
logf(x) = feval(symengine,'simplify',log(f),'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints');
logg(x) = feval(symengine,'simplify',log(g),'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints');
solve(logf(3) == logg(3), logf(4) == logg(4), mu,s)
```

yields good solutions.

---

#### Solution

Given `f(x)`, for each PDF `g(x)` we attempt to solve simultaneously

```
log(f(r1)) == log(g(r1)) and log(f(r2)) == log(g(r2))
```

for some simple non-equal numbers `r1`, `r2`. Then output `g` for which the solution has the lowest complexity.

---

The code is:

```matlab
function whichDist(f,x)

syms mu s L a b x0 x1 x2 v n p g

f = propto(f,x); % simplify up to proportionality
logf(x) = feval(symengine,'simplify',log(f),'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints');
Normal(mu,s,x) = propto((1/sqrt(2*pi*s)) * exp(-1/(2*s) * (x-mu)^2),x);
Exponential(L,x) = exp(-L*x);
Gamma(a,b,x) = x^(a-1)*exp(-b*x);
Beta(a,b,x) = x^(a-1)*(1-x)^(b-1);
ChiSq(v,x) = x^(v/2 - 1) * exp(-x/2);
tdist(v,x) = (1+x^2 / v)^(-(v+1)/2);
Cauchy(g,x0,x) = 1/(1+((x-x0)/g)^2);

logf = logf(x);
best_sol = {'none', inf};
r1 = randi(10); r2 = randi(10); r3 = randi(10);
while (r1 == r2 || r2 == r3 || r1 == r3) r1 = randi(10); r2 = randi(10); r3 = randi(10); end

%% check Exponential:
if (propto(logf,x) == x) % pdf ~ exp(K*x), can read off Lambda directly
    soln = -logf/x;
    if (~has(soln,x)) % any solution can't depend on x
        fprintf('\nExponential: rate L = %s\n\n', soln);
        return
    end
end

%% check Chi-sq:
if (propto(logf + x/2, log(x)) == log(x)) % can read off v directly
    soln = 2*(1+(logf + x/2) / log(x));
    if (~has(soln,x))
        dof = feval(symengine,'simplify',soln,'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints');
        fprintf('\nChi-Squared: v = %s\n\n', dof);
        return
    end
end

%% check t-dist:
h1 = propto(logf,x);
h = simplify(exp(h1) - 1);
if (propto(h,x^2) == x^2) % pdf ~ exp(K*x), can read off Lambda directly
    soln = simplify(x^2 / h);
    if (~has(soln,x))
        fprintf('\nt-dist: v = %s\n\n', soln);
        return
    end
end
h = simplify(exp(-h1) - 1); % try again if propto flipped a sign
if (propto(h,x^2) == x^2) % pdf ~ exp(K*x), can read off Lambda directly
    soln = simplify(x^2 / h);
    if (~has(soln,x))
        fprintf('\nt-dist: v = %s\n\n', soln);
        return
    end
end

%% check Normal:
logn(x) = feval(symengine,'simplify',log(Normal(mu,s,x)),'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints');
% A = (x - propto(logf/x, x))/2;
% B = simplify(-x/(logf/x - mu/s)/2);
% if (~has(A,x) && ~has(B,x))
%     fprintf('Normal: mu = %s, s^2 = %s', A, B);
%     return
% end
logf(x) = logf;
try % attempt to solve the equation
    % solve simultaneously for two random non-equal integer values r1,r2
    qn = solve(logf(r1) == logn(r1), logf(r2) == logn(r2), mu, s);
catch error
end
if (exist('qn','var')) % if solve() managed to run
    if (~isempty(qn.mu) && ~isempty(qn.s) && ~any(has([qn.mu,qn.s],x))) % if solution exists
        complexity = symlength(qn.mu) + symlength(qn.s);
        if complexity < best_sol{2} % store best solution so far
            best_sol{1} = sprintf('Normal: mu = %s, s^2 = %s', qn.mu, qn.s);
            best_sol{2} = complexity;
        end
    end
end


%% check Cauchy:
logcau(x) = feval(symengine,'simplify',log(Cauchy(g,x0,x)),'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints');
f(x) = f;
try
    qcau = solve(f(r1) == Cauchy(g,x0,r1), f(r2) == Cauchy(g,x0,r2), g, x0);
catch error
end
if (exist('qcau','var'))
    if (~isempty(qcau.g) && ~isempty(qcau.x0) && ~any(has([qcau.g(1),qcau.x0(1)],x)))
        complexity = symlength(qcau.g(1)) + symlength(qcau.x0(1));
        if complexity < best_sol{2}
            best_sol{1} = sprintf('Cauchy: g = %s, x0 = %s', qcau.g(1), qcau.x0(1));
            best_sol{2} = complexity;
        end
    end
end
f = f(x);

%% check Gamma:
logg(x) = feval(symengine,'simplify',log(Gamma(a,b,x)),'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints');
t = children(logf); t = [t{:}];
if (length(t) == 2)
    if (propto(t(1),log(x)) == log(x) && propto(t(2),x) == x)
        soln = [t(1)/log(x) + 1, -t(2)/x];
        if (~any(has(soln,x)))
            fprintf('\nGamma: shape a = %s, rate b = %s\n\n',soln);
            return
        end
    elseif (propto(t(2),log(x)) == log(x) && propto(t(1),x) == x)
        soln = [t(2)/log(x) + 1, -t(1)/x];
        if (~any(has(soln,x)))
            fprintf('\nGamma: shape a = %s, rate b = %s\n\n',soln);
            return
        end
    end
end
logf(x) = logf;
try % also try using solve(), just in case.
    qg = solve(logf(r1) == logg(r1), logf(r2) == logg(r2), a, b);
catch error
end
if (exist('qg','var'))
    if (~isempty(qg.a) && ~isempty(qg.b) && ~any(has([qg.a,qg.b],x)))
        complexity = symlength(qg.a) + symlength(qg.b);
        if complexity < best_sol{2}
            best_sol{1} = sprintf('Gamma: shape a = %s, rate b = %s', qg.a, qg.b);
            best_sol{2} = complexity;
        end
    end
end
logf = logf(x);

%% check Beta:
B = feval(symengine,'simplify',log(propto(f,x-1)),'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints');
if (propto(B,log(x-1)) == log(x-1))
    B = B / log(x-1) + 1;
    A = f / (x-1)^(B-1);
    A = feval(symengine,'simplify',log(abs(A)),'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints');
    if (propto(A,log(abs(x))) == log(abs(x)))
        A = A / log(abs(x)) + 1;
        if (~any(has([A,B],x)))
            fprintf('\nBeta1: a = %s, b = %s\n\n', A, B);
            return
        end
    end
elseif (propto(B,log(1-x)) == log(1-x))
    B = B / log(1-x);
    A = simplify(f / (1-x)^(B-1));
    A = feval(symengine,'simplify',log(A),'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints');
    if (propto(A,log(x)) == log(x))
        A = A / log(x) + 1;
        if (~any(has([A,B],x)))
            fprintf('\nBeta1: a = %s, b = %s\n\n', A, B);
            return
        end
    end
end

%% Print solution with lowest complexity
fprintf('\n%s\n\n', best_sol{1});

end
```

---

Tests:

```matlab
>> syms x y z
>> f = y^(1/2)*exp(-(x^2)/2 - y/2 * (1+(4-x)^2+(6-x)^2))
>> whichDist(f,x)
Normal: mu = (10*y)/(2*y + 1), s^2 = 1/(2*y + 1)
>> whichDist(f,y)
Gamma: a = 3/2, b = x^2 - 10*x + 53/2
>> Beta(a,b,x) = propto((1/beta(a,b)) * x^(a-1)*(1-x)^(b-1), x);
>> f = Beta(1/z + 7*y/(1-sqrt(z)), z/y + 1/(1-z), x)
Beta: a = -(7*y*z - z^(1/2) + 1)/(z*(z^(1/2) - 1)), b = -(y + z - z^2)/(y*(z - 1))
```

All correct.

Sometimes bogus answers if the parameters are numeric:

```matlab
whichDist(Beta(3,4,x),x)
Beta: a = -(pi*log(2)*1i + pi*log(3/10)*1i - log(2)*log(3/10) + log(2)*log(7/10) - log(3/10)*log(32) + log(2)*log(1323/100000))/(log(2)*(log(3/10) - log(7/10))), b = (pi*log(2)*1i + pi*log(7/10)*1i + log(2)*log(3/10) - log(2)*log(7/10) - log(7/10)*log(32) + log(2)*log(1323/100000))/(log(2)*(log(3/10) - log(7/10)))
```

So there is room for improvement and I will still award bounty to a better solution than this.

---

Edit: Added more distributions. Improved Gamma and Beta distribution identifications by spotting them directly without needing `solve()`.